# Command "clear-compiled" is not defined. Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, command, composer-php, laravel-5

I am trying to download Laravel HTML dependencies with Composer.

`composer.json` is here:

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.2"
    },
```

And when I run `composer update` or `php composer update`, the terminal log is:

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\lara-test>composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "clear-compiled" is not defined.

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock]
 [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-
progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
 [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--pre
fer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--] [<packages>]...
```

What is missing?
Please help.

Comment: try `composer update --no-scripts`

Comment: Thanks, Its working. But what is `--no scripts` ??

Answer (score 13):

You can get around this by using `composer update --no-scripts` which runs the update command from composer without the executing the scripts defined in the `composer.json` file.

As part of running `composer update` a script is executed which runs `php artisan clear-compiled` - effectively the update works as normal, just without compiled files being cleared.

There's a couple of blog posts on other work arounds: http://jianjye.com/fix-command-clear-compiled-not-defined-error-upgrading-laravel-5-2/ and an issue logged https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9678

Comment: Thank you, that helped me very much.

Comment: @raphael if you found it helpful would you mind up voting it?

Answer (score 0):

The current answer here does not satisfy someone who wants to perform `clear-compiled` action. Here is the solution with an equivalent script, (taken from https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9678)

Create a script at the laravel's root folder called `clear-compiled` with the contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/bootstrap/cache/*.*') as $file) {
    @unlink($file);
}
echo 'Cleared compiled directory.';
exit();
```

Then in `composer.json`, change `php artisan clear-compiled` to `php clear-compiled`:

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-install-cmd": [
        "php clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php clear-compiled"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error when migrating an old project from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2. The solution was running:

```
$ rm -Rf bootstrap/cache/*
```

This will clear cache manually and `php artisan clear-compiled` is gonna work again.

Ref: https://jianjye.com/p/fix-command-clear-compiled-not-defined-error-laravel/